# Django on virtual machine - watching changes in static files and autocompiling LESS without inotify

Tags: python, beginner, django, less-css

I'm setting up a Django development environment using Vagrant to run an Ubuntu virtual machine on VirtualBox. As this is a student project run mostly by very amateur coders and I want everyone to be able to contribute, I want the environment to be as convenient as possible.

What I'm trying to achieve:

- LESS-files would be compiled to CSS automatically whenever they are changed
- This automation would be run immediately on vagrant up, without any need to SSH the virtual machine.

I'm using django-pipeline (as it is supports Python3, unlike some other similar plugins) to manage my static files and compile LESS. Getting the files to compile automatically has proven a bit problematic though, since changing files in the shared folder from the host machine [does not trigger inotify events on the VirtualBox guest machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660). This rules out the most commonly used options for watching a folder for changes.

One option that I considered was using the Guard-gem with the -p (polling) option, but this would have required setting up Ruby, that I don't use elsewhere in the project, so I abandoned it as too complicated an option.

Inspired somewhat by Django's server's [way of monitoring files in the absence of inotify](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py#L147), I decided to write my own script for watching for changes in a folder and then run that script on screen in Vagrant's provisioning script. **I got it to work**, but since I feel like I have no idea what I'm doing, I want to ask:

1. Does this solution make any sense at all or would there have been an insanely easy solution to the original problem that I just missed?
2. I'm a newbie to Python. Does my code comply to the best practices of using Django and Python?
3. Did I just crack an enigmatic riddle puzzling millions worldwide or should I just be embarrassed about ever spending time on such a petty problem?

### The code

**myapp/management/commands/watchstatic.py:**

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.conf import settings
from pipeline.exceptions import CompilerError
import os
import sched
import time

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = 'Watches the static folder for changes, and runs the collectstatic-command if something is changed'
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):

        def get_time(filename):
            stat = os.stat(filename)
            mtime = stat.st_mtime
            return mtime

        def files_and_times(directory):
            files = []
            files_dict = {}
            for (dirpath, dirname, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
                for name in filenames:
                    files.append(dirpath + '/' + name)
            for filename in files:
                files_dict[filename] = get_time(filename)
            return files_dict

        def read_all():
            all_files = {}
            for key, sets in settings.WATCH_STATIC_FOLDERS.items():
                folder_dict = files_and_times(sets['folder'])
                all_files[key] = folder_dict
            return all_files

        def files_changed(sc, old_files={}):
            # Read new files and their modification times
            new_files = read_all()
            if new_files != old_files:
                print('Files changed!')
                try:
                    call_command('collectstatic', interactive=False)
                    # Delete the useless files created by django-pipeline
                    # See: https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/issues/202
                    for key, sets in settings.WATCH_STATIC_FOLDERS.items():
                        for filename in sets['delete']:
                            filepath = sets['folder'] + '/' + filename
                            os.remove(filepath)
                            print('Deleted ' + filepath)
                except CompilerError:
                    print('Failed to compile!')
                    # Just try again when the code is changed next time
                    pass
                old_files = read_all()
            sc.enter(settings.WATCH_INTERVAL, 1, files_changed, (sc, old_files))

        s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        # The files are always compiled on the first run
        s.enter(settings.WATCH_INTERVAL, 1, files_changed, (s,))
        s.run()
```

**settings.py:**

```
WATCH_INTERVAL = 5              # Seconds
WATCH_STATIC_FOLDERS = {
    'myapp': {
        'folder': 'myapp/static',
        'delete': (
            'bootstrap_less/bootstrap.css',
            'style.css'
        )
    }
}
```

**In Vagrant provisioning shell script:**

```
su - vagrant -c "cd /vagrant && screen -S watcher -d -m python manage.py watchstatic"
```

Comment: I'd recommend you look at using https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify or similar for this; it's the "corrrect" way to do it (certainly far more correct than walking through every single file ;))

Comment: pyinotify relies on inotify, that does not work in this scenario, as I explained.

Comment: I would avoid reinventing the wheel and use proven technology, in this case compass . Yes, it's ruby, but that's a one-line install so isn't too complex.

Comment: Watchdog ( https://github.com/samuelcolvin/watchgod ) is Python changes watcher without utilizing inotify, I'd use that instead of reinventing a wheel and encountering various bugs during that. For example in here `files_changed(sc, old_files={})` you have a dictionary as a default value which might cause issues, see https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments